# jQuery - change the CSS of the menu item's path in the dynamically created menu

Tags: jquery

I'm using that jQuery Vertical Menu Library [www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddsmoothmenu.htm](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddsmoothmenu.htm) I want to accomplish the selection of the selected path. Let's say that I go through that menu (in the demo on that site above) by the path:

```
Folder 2 > Folder 2.1 > Folder 3.1.1 > SubItem 3.1.1.1
```

When I click on the `SubItem 3.1.1.1` I want that the all previous items (from the path above) changes their backgrounds. The code below selects only the top-most item. How to fix that ?

```
    $('#nav > li').click(function () {
        $(this).children('a').css('background-color', 'red'); 
        $(this).parents('ul').each(function () { $(this).prev('a').css('background-color', 'red'); });
    });
```

. In that scenario, my code fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the menu seems to be organized, the click event will bubble up from child `li` to parent `li`, so you just need to bind the click event to all menu items and set the background for the current element:

```
$('#nav li').click(function () {
    $(this).children('a').css('background-color', 'red'); 
});
```

You still might like to unset the red background when you click on another menu item

Comment: Weird. I tested it on the jQuery Vertical Menu Library link you sent, with a debugger (like Firebug): (`$('#smoothmenu2 li').click(function() {$(this).children('a').css('background-color', 'red');})`) and it worked perfectly. Try it and yourself. If you can't see what's wrong, try to create a fiddle that reproduces the problem

Comment: According to the unsetting the Red background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884987/jquery-strange-function-behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Solve attempt #1:

```
    $('#nav a').click(function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        $('a.selected').css('background-color', 'red');
    });
```

Comment: won't work, because of the way the menu's structured: `li > a`, `li > ul`, `ul` > `li`, the event bubbles from the `a` clicked to `li` to `ul` to `li` etc.