# jQuery - strange function behaviour

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have the `UL` list and the code which selects the all parents of the selected `LI` element (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8883690/106616). Now, I want to clear the selection when I select the other LI element.
To do so, I've created that code:

(simply, before select the new path, I iterate through the array to clear the previous selection, then I clear the array and while selecting the new path I add new items to that array)

```
    $('#nav li').click(function () {
        //clear the previous selection
        $.each(myArray, function (i, v) {
            console.log('loop: ' + v);
            $('#nav li a[href="' + v + '"]').css('background-color', 'Green');
        });

        myArray.lenght = 0;

        //add the new selection
        $(this).children('a').each(function (item) {
            myArray.push($(this).attr('href'));
            console.log('adding: ' + $(this).attr('href'));
            $(this).css('background-color', 'Red');
        });
    });
```

but, that code generates that output if I select the 1st path.

> adding: #/1210
>
> loop: #/1210
>
> adding: #/1209
>
> loop: #/1210
>
> loop: #/1209
>
> adding: #/1208

If I select the e.g. 2nd path, the output is:

> loop: #/1210
>
> loop: #/1209
>
> loop: #/1208
>
> adding: #/1188
>
> loop: #/1210
>
> loop: #/1209
>
> loop: #/1208
>
> loop: #/1188
>
> adding: #/1187

I think the output should be (the 2nd path selection)

> loop: #/1210
>
> loop: #/1209
>
> loop: #/1208
>
> adding: #/1188
>
> adding: #/1187

Can someone explain this for me ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  The only one I see is that `myArray.lenght = 0;` has `length` misspelled.

Comment: Instead of changing the background of the actual path to red, only the forst (the top-most) element is red, the others are green

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click event originates from an `a` element. So catch it first before it bubbles to the first `li`, and make all the `a`s default. Then continue with [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883404/jquery-change-the-css-of-the-menu-items-path-in-the-dynamically-created-menu/8883690#8883690)

```
$('#nav a').click(function() {
    $('#nav a').css('background-color', 'green'); 
});
$('#nav li').click(function () {
    $(this).children('a').css('background-color', 'red'); 
});
```

**But it's much better to do this whole thing with CSS classes:**

```
$('#nav a').click(function() {
    $('#nav a.current').removeClass('current'); 
});
$('#nav li').click(function () {
    $(this).children('a').addClass('current'); 
});
```

And in CSS:

```
#nav a { background-color: green; }
#nav a.current { background-color: red }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your menu likely has nested `li` elements so when you click on one, the event bubbles up, triggering your callback and clearing previously selected elements.  You can prevent the event from bubbling and just select all of the ancestor `li` elements to set their children's styles.

```
$('#nav li').click(function () {
    //clear the previous selection
    $('#nav li > a').css("background-color", "green");

    //add the new selection
    $(this).parentsUntil("#nav", "li").children("a").css("background-color", "red");

    return false; //Prevent the default action and prevent the event from bubbling up.
});
```

You may also want to use a class and define styles for those instead of using inline styles.  It is more maintainable in the future if you decide you don't like the colors or want additional styling.